# Select Multiple Excel Sheets to Export to PDF

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I have some code written to build a list of worksheets in a string based on if the user selects a checkbox to include the sheet in the PDF report. See below:

```
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        PDFsheets = "Sheet11"    
End If

If CheckBox2.Value = True Then
    If PDFsheets = "" Then
        PDFsheets = "Sheet13"
    Else
        PDFsheets = PDFsheets & ",Sheet13"
    End If
End If

If CheckBox3.Value = True Then
    If PDFsheets = "" Then
        PDFsheets = "Sheet2"
    Else
        PDFsheets = PDFsheets & ",Sheet2"
    End If
End If
```

For example, when all 3 checkboxes are selected, `MsgBox PDFsheets` shows the result `Sheet11, Sheet13, Sheet2`

NOW, when I try to do a multiple sheet select I get Run-Time Error 9 - Subscript Out of Range. The different things I've tried include:

`ThisWorkBook.Sheets(PDFsheets).Select`

---

`ThisWorkBook.Sheets(Array(PDFsheets)).Select`

---

```
xPDF() = Split(PDFsheets, ",")
ThisWorkBook.Sheets(xPDF).Select
```

---

```
xPDF() = Split(PDFsheets, ",")
ThisWorkBook.Sheets(Array(xPDF)).Select
```

---

```
xPDF() = Split(PDFsheets, ",")

For i = 0 to Application.CountA(xPDF) - 1
    Sheets(xPDF(i)).Select
next i
```

---

ALSO, for the sake of brevity I have tried all of the above examples with ActiveWorkbook instead of ThisWorkBook. PLUS, I've tried rewriting my string building part to reference the sheets names instead of numbers with all of the examples above. So instead of `Sheet11, Sheet13, Sheet2` the result was `"Sheet11", "Sheet13, "Sheet2"` with the double quotes around the sheets.

I've look at other questions and code examples on here and elsewhere that show this same goal and I'm using the selection line exactly as they have had it and I'm getting the Subscript out of range error. (I've also verified everything is spelled correctly)

**Additional Note** if I try typing the string value directly in it works - `ThisWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet11, Sheet13, Sheet2").Select` - However, this doesn't allow me to keep it variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are building a comma separated string that you must convert into an array.  You were **very** close:

```
Sub BuildAString()
    Dim PDFsheets As String
    Dim s As Worksheet
    PDFsheets = "Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3"
    ary = Split(PDFsheets, ",")

    Sheets(ary).Select
    Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
            "C:\TestFolder\Book1.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
            True
End Sub
```

Note this makes **1** pdf file for all three sheets.  You would use a loop if you wanted **3** separate files.
Note that there are no spaces in`PDFsheets` because my worksheet names have no spaces.

Comment: I'm still get the subscript out of range error. Another thought I had that could be causing the issue is that the workbook has multiple windows. I've tried adding a `Windows("WindowName").Activate` for each each different window before the select line, but get the same error regardless.

Comment: @SincereApathy  **Please note that I do not include a space character in the string of sheet names.** ..................your tab names probably do **not** begin with a space character !!

Comment: I've tried it both ways and currently have the space deleted out.

Comment: I figured it out... I had only tried sheet number without quotes example:`Sheet11` or sheet name with quotes example: `"Cost Analysis"`. Finally got it to work by using sheet name without quotes ... `Cost Anaylsis`. Sorry, I should have used the actual names in my example, but thought if I used the sheet number as the sheet name it would make it easier to follow. Thanks for your help, learned a lesson here.